# data.table error Error in alloc.col(ans) : object 'Csetmutable' not found

Tags: r, data.table

data.table is throwing error. It was working correctly until Nov. 5 but suddenly stopped working

Error in alloc.col(ans) : object 'Csetmutable' not found

> DT = data.table(ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"), a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c = 13:18)

Error in alloc.col(ans) : object 'Csetmutable' not found

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling the package from CRAN?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Re-installing package did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-installing package data.table from CRAN (as suggested by Frank) solved the issue.